# Using TabularInline in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I am trying to show the `orderitemsadmin` in the `orderadmin` using TabularInline but I keep getting different errors like the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'OrderItemAdmin' object has no attribute 'urls'
```

and

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth.User' that has not been installed
```

This is a Django e-commerce project and I am trying to facilitating the admin viewing the orders and their items.

I don't have much experience in using TabularInline that is why I am not able to do it corrrectly or what might be the mistake that I am doing.

Here is the admin.py

```
class OrderItemAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    list_display = ['item', 'quantity', 'ordered']
    model = OrderItem
    raw_id_fields = ['item']


class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'ordered', 'ordered_date', 'coupon', 'payment', 'shipping_address', 'status',
                    'refund_requested', 'refund_granted', 'ref_code']
    inlines = [
        OrderItemAdmin,
    ]
admin.site.register(OrderItem, OrderItemAdmin)
admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

Here is the models.py

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Order(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your code to be like this

```
class OrderItemTabular(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OrderItem


class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'ordered', 'ordered_date', 'coupon', 'payment', 'shipping_address', 'status',
                    'refund_requested', 'refund_granted', 'ref_code']
    inlines = [
        OrderItemTabular,
    ]

admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

first we create the tabular class which contains the model we want to show in our model , then we use this class in our model customization class OrderAdmin then we register our model with it's customization class

Comment: i am getting this error with this code: `ERRORS:
<class 'core.admin.OrderItemTabular'>: (admin.E202) 'core.OrderItem' has no ForeignKey to 'core.Order'.`

Comment: there is must be a ForeignKey  relation between the OrderItem and the Order in your models , it seems that you forget it

Comment: So my issue here is that I can't set a foreign relation with `OrderItem` and `Order` as the sequence is: `Orderitem` which has a `foreign` relation with `Item`, and `Order` which has a `manytomany` relation with `OrderItem`, if the switched their location or sequence it will mess with the `ManytoMany` relation. Is there a way around, thank you